# Downsides to MERGE with dummy USING table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, merge

I'm creating some stored procedures specifically for use from C# to update various tables in our database.  A large number of items require a predictable function that will:

1)  Check if a matching row already exists
2)  If it doesn't exist, insert data
3)  Gather ID of row and return to user

I know this can be done in a number of ways, but the most elegant way I can imagine seems to be using a MERGE with a dummy table and using the procedure params for the ON clause, such as:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.UpdatePerson(@PersonID INT, @FirstName VARCHAR(50)) AS
    MERGE dbo.Person p
    USING (SELECT 1 One) One
    ON p.Person_ID = @PersonID
    WHEN MATCHED THEN 
        UPDATE SET First_Name = @FirstName
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT (Person_ID, First_Name) VALUES (@PersonID, @FirstName);
```

This wraps it all together in one nice bundle, even though I'm not working with an actual table to merge in.  I know the same basic idea could be accomplished with:

```
...
USING (SELECT @PersonID Person_ID, @FirstName First_Name) NewPerson
ON p.Person_ID = NewPerson.Person_ID
...
```

and maybe this would offer some kind of performance benefit?

Can anyone offer any solid reasons for/against this kind of usage of MERGE?

Comment: From my understanding Merge is a set operation for "upsert" scenario. In your stored procedure, ID and name are passed in individually. So I don't think this pattern has any advantage better than "IF EXISTS ELSE" pattern

Comment: It just feels more compact and clear; is there any DOWNSIDE to it?  Or are they essentially interchangeable?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using MERGE you can use if condition.

You are having a temp table

```
CREATE TABLE #Table(PersonID INT,First_Name VARCHAR(100))

-- BEFORE THAT INSERT INTO TEMP TABLE 

IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM YOURTABLE WHERE PERSONID IN(SELECT PERSONID FROM #TABLE)) 
BEGIN
    -------YOUR UPDATE QUERY
END 
ELSE
BEGIN
    -------INSERT QUERY
END

DROP TABLE #Table
```

Comment: I understand this is a possibility, but it just seems like more code and less elegant.  Is there any downside to using a merge rather than this approach?